# iterate in parent element and get text nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn DOM scrapping using jquery. I have a structure like this

```
<p>
            A. liver.
            <br> B. diaphragm.
            <br> C. esophagus.
            <br> D. pancreas.
</p>
```

How can I iterate in this *P tag* and get **TEXT NODES** in an array,, e.g [A-Text,BText,CText,DText], I do not want *`<br> tag`*.
Please help I could not figure it out, how to loop in P tag childs and segregate text nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this using jQuery you can use a combination of `contents()` to get all the nodes within the parent, then `filter()` to get the textNodes only. Try this:

```js
var textNodeArray = $('p').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.textContent.trim();
}).get();

/* for demo purposes */
textNodeArray.forEach(function(node) {
  console.log(node.textContent.trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  A. liver.
  <br>B. diaphragm.
  <br>C. esophagus.
  <br>D. pancreas.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contents` function to get the children of the `p` element (including text and comment nodes) and then use `filter` to reduce collection to only nodes of text type.

```
  var arr = [];
  var getTextNodesContent = function(el) {
      return $(el).children().addBack().contents().filter(function() {
           var isTextNode = this.nodeType == 3;
           if (isTextNode) {
              arr.push($(this).text().trim())
           }
          return this.nodeType == 3;
      });
  };
  getTextNodesContent($('p'))
  console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/), [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/) functions:

```js
var textNodes = $('p').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).map(function(i, n){
    return n.nodeValue.trim();
}).get();

console.log(textNodes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  A. liver.
  <br> B. diaphragm.
  <br> C. esophagus.
  <br> D. pancreas.
</p>
```